# MacOS Mojave - load unsigned kernel extension

Tags: macos, mojave, kernel-extensions

in macOS mojave one can't simply load unsgined kexts:

```
$ sudo kextutil -l /Applications/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/Driver.kext
Untrusted kexts are not allowed
```

What should I do to be allowed (besides a dev cert..)?

Will these do?:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1
csrutil enable --without kext
```

- manually allowing via the GUI?

Comment: Will this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672670/macos-kext-with-invalid-signature

Comment: Umm basically saying allow via the GUI right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two avenues to get the extension whitelisted:

1. Manage the mac using MDM and follow the steps to have your MDM pre-clear this specific extension.
2. Open the Security System Preferences and click to white list this extension once you have attempted to load it one time.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2459/_index.html

The above article has the two buttons you need to click in the GUI to white list each extension on each machine.